# Capitalize a match in search and replace

Tags: regular-expression, replace, find, search-replace

I am using the following regex to find the first letter of the last word on each line in a file:

`%s/.* .\zs/`

I want to now lower case this match on every line in a file. How do I do it?

For eg.

Before: Insomnia Cures

After : Insomnia cures

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
:%s/\S\+\s*$/\l&/
```

The `\S\+` match any non space characters (a word)

Since its is followed by `\s*$`, that only match trailing spaces at the end of the line, this word must be at the end of the line.

The `\l` transforms the match by changing the first letter to lowercase.

You can find more information at: `:help :s%` for the transformation possibilities.

You can find also more information about patterns at `:help pattern-overview`.

Comment: Thanks @Rich it seems I read the question toi fast :-/

Comment: We've all been there!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
%s/.*\zs \([A-Z]\)/\L&/
```

If you want to consider lines like

> Insomnia (Cures)

you can use `%s/.*\zs [^A-Z]\?\([A-Z]\)/\L&/`

To manipulate strings at the beginning of the line you can use
`%s/^\([^a-z][A-Z]\)/\L&/`

Comment: Welcome to Vim. We recommend you to add some explanation to your answer to guide the readers.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific task, an alternative approach is not to use a `:substitute` command at all!

```
:%norm!$Bgul

 %             # On every line,
  norm!        # Run the normal mode commands:
       $       # Move to the end of the line,
        B      # Move to the start of the last WORD on the line, and
         gu    # Convert to lower case...
           l   # The first letter of the word.
```